# Crop data for Europe / Germany

Tags: data, land-cover, europe, land-use, germany

I am currently working on the effect of land use on streams in very small catchments (<30km²) in Germany. We have accurate data (ATKIS) on general land use patterns (forests, agriculture, urban areas etc.). We also try to incorporate information about crop types (CAPRI data) in the agricultural areas into our analysis. However the CAPRI data we use is quite coarse: Aggregated between 2001 and 2003 and a spatial solution of 1000x1000m. http://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/european-food-safety-authority-efsa-data-persam-software-tool

Is there any open source data on specific crop types in Europe (or Germany) for certain years other than CAPRI?

Comment: I think the place to research/ask open data questions is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You should almost certainly start your research by looking at the INSPIRE geoportal ~ http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/discovery/

Any public body in German that has any data that falls under the scope of the INSPIRE spatial data themes, which includes land use, must publish metadata about those data to the INSPIRE metadata catalogue.  You can explore those metadata in the portal.

I was able to find 30066 metadata records for `Germany` + `Land Use`.